# Implementing a custom comparator with a functor template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to write custom comparators for functions like `lower_bound`, `find`, etc. Below is an example of a custom comparator implemented with a functor that takes another function object (`std::less`, `std::greater`, etc) and use it to compare the first element of a pair with the second argument of the function.

```
template <template <typename> class P = std::less>
struct custom_comp {
    template <class T1, class T2>
    bool operator()(const std::pair<T1, T2>& pair, const T1& val)
    {
            return P<T1>()(pair.first, val);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
vector<pair<int,int>> vec = {{1, 4}, {3, 3}, {5, 6}, {8, 8}};
auto first = lower_bound(begin(vec), end(vec), 5, custom_comp<>());
```

However the `<>()` bothers me, I feel it takes away readability. Is there a way to get rid of it? (perhaps changing the functor for another kind of structure).

btw: I don't want to use lambdas because I want to reuse these custom comparators and even extend them to take more template arguments (like custom filters, e.g a functor that takes a pair and returns `pair.first`, or a functor that takes the mean of a vector, etc).

Comment: You could change `custom_comp` to `custom_comp_whatever`, then create the `custom_comp_whatever<> custom_comp() {}` `template<template<class> class P> custom_comp_whatever<P> custom_comp() {}` free overloaded functions providing the actual comparator, would that suit you?

Comment: Enhance readability with custom_less, custom greater, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However the `<>()` bothers me

It shouldn't. Nothing wrong with that code. Sometimes you need to do that sort of thing. It doesn't really take away from readability, it's pretty clear what's going on there.

If you want, you could always just create the "default" `custom_comp`:

```
constexpr custom_comp<> def_custom_comp{};
```

And then use it:

```
auto first = lower_bound(begin(vec), end(vec), 5, def_custom_comp);
```

You lose the `<>()`, but I'm not sure that's necessarily easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks, dropping prior comment, but keeping my preference to the original bothersome syntax. I prefer seeing `custom_comp<>()` because it announces to the reader "this is an instance of a template with default template parameters", something shrouded when using an intermediary. and thanks for fixing it.